# What matters it & What does it matter

Tags: grammar, meaning

Does "what matters it" means "What does it matter" ?
Source:https://www.storynory.com/alice-in-wonderland-chapter-10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does - in old-fashioned or poetic language. Lewis Carroll has used it here to fit the rhythm of the Mock Turtle's song.